# Kendo UI Chart - Updating datasource after databound

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dataviz, kendo-datasource

I have some actions that need to be executed during/after databinding of my charts.

One of the things is that I'm adding missing categories (months). My problem is that if I add those missing values to the datasource, it triggers the databound event again.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<MyModel>()
    .Name("chart")
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Home")))
    .CategoryAxis(a => a.Date().Categories(c => c.Date))
    .ValueAxis(v => v.Numeric().Min(0).Max(100))
    .Series(series => series.Column(d => d.Value))
    .Events(e => e.DataBound("dataBound"))
)

function dataBound(e) {
    var chart = e.sender;
    var today = new Date(); 
    // Add current month to chart
    chart.dataSource.add({
        CategoryDate: today,
        Value: 0
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time data inside `DataSource` is added, modified or deleted `DataSource` will trigger event `Change`, and every widget which has `DataSource` will trigger event `DataBound` after `DataSource` is changed.

Therefore your `DataBound` event is triggered twice, whereas your chart using remote service to `Read` its data, internally there are 2 events which will be trigger to achieve it. Event `RequestStart` and `RequestEnd` will be called, so I suggest you add your missing category inside the datasource `RequestEnd` event.

Inside the `RequestEnd` event you can modify its response data, you could debug it to see the full structure of this response; normally it will have the `Data` property and this is the property that you need to change.

**Sample Code**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<MyModel>()
    .Name("chart")
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Home"))
                        .Events(evt => evt.RequestEnd("onChartDsRequestEnd")))
    .CategoryAxis(a => a.Date().Categories(c => c.Date))
    .ValueAxis(v => v.Numeric().Min(0).Max(100))
    .Series(series => series.Column(d => d.Value))
    .Events(e => e.DataBound("dataBound"))
)

function onChartDsRequestEnd(e) {
    // data you should modify before its being placed as datasource's data
    var responseData = e.response;
    responseData.push({.......});
}
```

[Datasource RequestEnd Documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-requestEnd)